# Shopify cart reduce quantity Ajax opposite of Shopify.addItem()

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, shopify-api

For transparency: this is an exact copy of a request that I have made in a Shopify forum, but I did not get any help there (except for an expensive offer to solve the issue...).

I own a Shopify store that uses a popup cart before checkout. I am using the following code on the popup cart, in order to enable customers to increase or decrease the quantity of items in the cart:

```html
<div class="input-group m-0">
      <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
      <input id="{{ item.variant.id }}" type="number" step="1" max="" value="{{ item.quantity }}" name="quantity" class="quantity-field">
      <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity" onclick="Shopify.addItem({{ item.variant.id }}, 1)">
</div>
```

As you might see I am using the Shopify.addItem() function when onclick is triggered in order to increase the amount of items per product in the cart. This function really works. Sadly I did not find any function to reduce the quantity by 1. So therefore I wrote some JavaScript, but it sadly does not work. Find the code here:

```js
$('.input-group').on('click', '.button-minus', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
    var parent = $(e.target).closest('div');
    var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);
    var currentVariant = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').attr('id'), 10);
    jQuery.post('/cart/change.js', { quantity: currentVal - 1, id: currentVariant });    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `currentVal` & `currentVariant` declaration is wrong. Need to add " inside a property

```
var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name="' + fieldName + '"]').val(), 10);
var currentVariant = parseInt(parent.find('input[name="' + fieldName + '"]').attr('id'), 10);
```

+ jQuery.post needs to be in an `aysnc ... await` function. Try this

```
$('.input-group').on('click', '.button-minus', async function(e) {
  ......
  await jQuery.post('/cart/change.js', { quantity: currentVal - 1, id: currentVariant });    
});
```

The above should work, but wouldn't it be nifty if we can use `Shopify.removeItem` ? Create a function like this and add it to scripts.js.liquid file

```
Shopify.removeItem = async function(id,quantity){
  await $.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    url:'/cart/change.js',
    data:{ id:id, quantity:(--quantity) },
    dataType: 'json'
  })
}
```

and change the quantity buttons to

```
<div class="input-group m-0">
  <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity" onclick="Shopify.removeItem({{ item.variant.id }},{{ item.quantity }})">
  <input id="{{ item.variant.id }}" type="number" step="1" max="" value="{{ item.quantity }}" name="quantity" class="quantity-field">
  <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity" onclick="Shopify.addItem({{ item.variant.id }}, 1)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the results from HymnZ. Sadly the provided code needed small changes to work in my shop. Find it below! And honors to HymnZ for the hint to the solution!

```js
Shopify.reduceItem = function(variant_id, quantity, callback) {
  var quantity = quantity;
  quantity = quantity-1;
  var params = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/change.js',
    data: 'quantity=' + quantity + '&id=' + variant_id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(line_item) {
      if ((typeof callback) === 'function') {
        callback(line_item);
      }
      else {
        Shopify.cartPopap(variant_id);
        Shopify.onItemAdded(line_item);
      }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
      Shopify.onError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus);
    }
  };
  jQuery.ajax(params);
};
```

Comment: I came back to add that you'd need to tweak it as how Shopify.addItem function works, but you already posted it here. I'm curious, what theme is this? I haven't seen such good code in recent times on Shopify themes.

Comment: All that I posted here is 100% custom code. So the input group was my own and also the JavaScript. I am also a little disappointed of my theme so as of now I am changing so much so in the theme code so that it runs as I want... For completeness, I am using the Corano theme. After the fist positive feelings I got more and more angry about the coding style - but this seems to be normal for Shopify templates

Comment: If that's the case, have a look at cartjs.org